How to block certain dates on WooCommerce shipping date field?
I am using a Checkout Field Editor (Checkout Manager) for WooCommerce 3rd party plugin, to add a custom field to the shipping section that allows the user to select a shipping date.
It displays a date picker.
Using custom code, is it possible to block certain dates (for example November 1-3, 2024) so that the user cannot choose those?


You need to use custom code with a JavaScript date-picker instead that allows to make extensive date customizations, than HTML 5 input date field allows.

Thanks! What if I am using the following custom code: https://www.reddit.com/r/woocommerce/comments/1fo7vbe/how_to_add_custom_fields_to_the_new_checkout_flow/loo1rpt/

The code from reddit uses the same html5 date input field… So you need to use one of these answers for example with a jQuery date picker, where you will be able to make customizations that the  html5 date input field doesn't allow.

Going to try that, thanks!
